# Deploy large war file in tom cat web application manager

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, war

I have been trying to deploy my war file through tomcat web application manager but always end up with the uploadFileSizeExceeded Exception (Please see the picture below). Is there any way I can do to deploy large war file? I have tried to change the maximum file size, advised [here](https://github.com/annotationsatharvard/catcha/issues/26) but still facing the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :) [image]

Comment: The fix in the link should work, did you restarted tomcat after the change? Perhaps reloading `manager`app is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think easy way is using **winscp** or similar fttp client to transfer the war file and restart the server.

Comment: I am still very new. Can I get more detailed instructions? I am sorry for the trouble and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzXPAAcGXY8  please watch the video it is demonstrate the connecting to server. Also make sure that, tomcat server is shut-downed using 'sudo ./shutdown.sh' command before deploying the 'war'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to Tomcat server version 7 and above, there is a configuration property called maxSwallowSize that you may have to set or change.

This property specifies the maximum number of bytes that Tomcat will “swallow” for an upload from the client when it knows the server will ignore the file.

The default value of the property is 2097152 (2 MB). If left unchanged or if set below the 5 MB limit that we set in our MultipartResolver, Tomcat will reject any attempt to upload a file over 2 MB, and our custom exception handling will never be invoked.

In order for the request to be successful and for the error message from the application to be displayed, you need to set maxSwallowSize property to a negative value. This instructs Tomcat to swallow all failed uploads regardless of file size.

Give a try with this in the TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml file:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="8443"
  maxSwallowSize = "-1"/>
```

for more details refer http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

Comment: I tried it but still, it doesn't solve my problem. :(

Comment: then download winscp from https://winscp.net/eng/download.php and install then you can connect to your server and transfer files using drag and drop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. But still, it doesn't solve my problem. I received permission denied error message while trying to transfer my war file using winscp. :(

Comment: If server is linux then option 1 is to use root user account or option 2 is to give all permission by running sudo chmod 777 -R /directory then it will work.